# Import multiple XLS files into SQL Server each one with a different Sheet Name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, excel, xls, vba

What's the easiest way to import 500 XLS files all with the same structure but each one with its own unique Sheet name ...into SQL Server?

Alternatively, I have combined ALL XLS files into a single XLS file but each sheet name is now unique within the XLS file.

Comment: Use `SSIS` for this task . No need to combine the files.Since you have the same `metadata` ,you can just loop all the files in a folder and dump the data into sql server

Answer (score 0):

I found these 2 VBA that helped me complete the job.

The 1st one combines all XLS in one directory into a single XLS and creates a unique Worksheet for each XLS file.

```
Sub Merge_Multiple_XLS_Into_WorkSheets()
    Path = "C:\Folder\"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xls")
    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
        For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Next Sheet
        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

The 2nd one combining all Sheets into a single one

```
Sub Merge_Sheets_Into_One()
    Const sRANGE = "A2:Z100"
    Dim iSheet, iTargetRow As Long, oCell As Object, bRowWasNotBlank As Boolean
    Dim iTop, iLeft, iBottom, iRight As Long
    Sheets(1).Select: Sheets.Add
    Sheets(1).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Clear
    bRowWasNotBlank = True
    For iSheet = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count: DoEvents
    For Each oCell In Sheets(iSheet).Range(sRANGE).Cells: DoEvents
    If oCell.Column = 1 Then
    If bRowWasNotBlank Then iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
    bRowWasNotBlank = False
    End If
    If oCell.MergeCells Then
    bRowWasNotBlank = True
    If oCell.MergeArea.Cells(1).Row = oCell.Row Then
    If oCell.MergeArea.Cells(1).Column = oCell.Column Then
    Sheets(1).Cells(iTargetRow, oCell.Column) = oCell
    iTop = iTargetRow
    iLeft = oCell.Column
    iBottom = iTop + oCell.MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1
    iRight = iLeft + oCell.MergeArea.Columns.Count - 1
    Sheets(1).Range(Cells(iTop, iLeft), Cells(iBottom, iRight)).MergeCells = True
    End If
    End If
    End If
    If Len(oCell) Then bRowWasNotBlank = True
    Sheets(1).Cells(iTargetRow, oCell.Column) = oCell
    Next oCell
    Next
    Sheets(1).Activate
End Sub
```

...and after running these 2 VBS scripts, it's just a matter of running Import Data wizard inside from the MS-SQL Management Studio.

Hope this helps...